# iOS: Presenting multiple modal view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to present two modal view controllers one after the other. According to the requirement I cannot dismiss the first one either. First modal is a popup view and the second modal is the camera in UIImagepicker controller. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://xissburg.com/presenting-multiple-modal-view-controllers-at-once/